# Having trouble dismissing dialog in Android [AlertDialog]

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

```
final String[] choices = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"};

final AlertDialog dialog= new AlertDialog.Builder(
    TestSubjectCalendar.this)
    .setTitle("Title")
    .setSingleChoiceItems(choices, pos, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss(); //gives error
            // MORE CODE
        }
    }).create();
    dialog.show();
```

`dialog.dismiss()` is giving the following errors:

> The local variable dialog may not have been initialized

What I want is that when I click an item from the choice list in the `dialog`, the `dialog` should disappear. So how can I go about doing that?

PS: I know I can use `setItems()` instead of `setSingleChoiceItems()`, but I want to use the latter as it provides radio buttons.

Comment: Can you show full code where you are witting this code in which event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change name of the dialog because there is same name use for **AlertDialog** and **DialogInterface** in *onClick()*...

Try following changes and checked it out.

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog1, int which) {
      dialog1.dismiss(); //gives error
      // MORE CODE
 }
```

That is resolve the name override, I just change **dialog** to **dialog1** in onClick().

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 final String[] choices = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"};

final AlertDialog.Builder dialog= new AlertDialog.Builder(TestSubjectCalendar.this);

dialog.setTitle("Title")
.setSingleChoiceItems(choices, pos, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss(); //gives error
        // MORE CODE
    }
}).create();
dialog.show();
```

Comment: I too tried this. But this give the error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from AlertDialog.Builder to AlertDialog`.

Comment: Now this error: `The method dismiss() is undefined for the type AlertDialog.Builder`

Answer (score 0):

Basically since you reference dialog in the same code block that dialog is initialized, `Eclipse/Java` compiler is concerned that the dialog reference used in `onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)` may be invalid.

So changing it to:

```
    final AlertDialog dialog= new AlertDialog.Builder(
            TestSubjectCalendar.this).create();
            dialog.setTitle("Title");
            dialog.setSingleChoiceItems(choices, pos, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss(); //gives error
                    // MORE CODE
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
```

should do the trick. On a side note, I don't actually get any error with your code, may have to do with compiler setting.

Comment: Doing what you have written gives the following error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from AlertDialog.Builder to AlertDialog`